# Import data to Firestore with Firebase Admin SDK (NodeJS) doesn't work for all collections

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using Firestore as a DB for my React web-app. Before browser tests with cypress are run, I execute a NodeJS script which imports data needed for those tests. My Firebase plan is set to Blaze(pay as you go) as the free version doesn't support import.

I have 3 collections where I import the data - organizations, profiles, products. **Using the same code, import works for organizations and profiles, but not products**:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: `https://<myFirebaseProjectId>.firebaseio.com`
});

const testOrg = {
  name: "testOrgName",
  createdAt: Date()
};

//add organization
admin.firestore().collection("organizations").add(testOrg)
  .then(createdTestOrg => {
     //works fine with organizations
     console.log("Successfully created new org:", createdTestOrg.id);
     const testProfile = {
       name: "testProfile",
       organization: admin.firestore().doc(`organizations/${createdTestOrg.id}`)       
       createdAt: Date()
     };

     //add profiles
     admin.firestore().collection("profiles").add(testprofile)
     .then(createdTestProfile => {
        //works fine with profile
        console.log("Successfully created new profile:", createdTestProfile .id);

       let productItem = {
         isDeleted: false,
         createdBy: admin.firestore().doc('profiles/' + selectedUser[0].uid),
         createdAt: Date()
       };            
       productItem.name = makeRandomName(10)

       //add product
       admin.firestore().collection("products").add(productItem)
       .then((newProd)=>{
          // I never get here
          console.log("Successfully created test product");
       })
      .catch(error => {
         // I never get here either
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
         console.log("Error creating test product:", error);
         process.exit(1);
       });
     });
  });
```

Here's Gist with a full code: https://gist.github.com/DurkoMatko/1097d1c18a00d5fd4195253205c53ff2

I've also tried replacing `collection("products").add(product)` with `collection("products").doc(product.id).set(product)` which should create new document if it doesn't exist yet. Still no success. Also, breakpoints in neither `.then` nor .`catch` section trigger. Those lines just silently happen but new product document doesn't get created.

Does someone please have any idea?

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance where neither the `then` or `catch` are executed.  A good suspect on products collection would be a security rule preventing create, but that would be caught in a catch.

Comment: @danh yeah I don't get it...I have just an easy console.log statement in both `then` and `catch` and code just never gets there..

And regarding security rules. You mean "firestore rules"? Doesn't firebase-admin surpass them? But yeah, the main problem is the then/catch issue anyway..

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code sample.  Right now, we have no idea what `testOrg` is.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added it now. Removed a loop for adding several products so the code is shorter. I'm trying to add 5 product documents. That's the only difference compared to adding to organizations or profiles documents. I've also tried `productItem` variable to be const and just hardcode its name within curly braces with other properties. I've also tried to add product just with `name` or just with `createdAt`properties.

I mean - Firestore is NoSQL no-schema DB right? Documents in the same collection can have different formats right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this by creating product directly as parameter of `.add` function rather than storing it as `const` variable before passing it to `.add`.  I have no idea why this works and the code I've posted in my question doesn't. Hope it helps someone in the future.

```js
 admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .add({ 
        name: "BrowserTestProduct26",
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        createdBy: admin.firestore().doc(`profiles/${userRecord.uid}`),
        isDeleted: false,
        category: categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)]
     })
     .then(createdProduct => {
        console.log("Successfully created new product:", createdProduct.id);
     })
     .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error creating test product:", error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
```